# gdb - how to step into a multi-line macro

Tags: gcc, macros, gdb

I'm debugging the following function from [Micropython](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/v1.9.2/py/gc.c#L317) and I'm unable to step into the code of the macro `VERIFY_MARK_AND_PUSH`.

I'm able to step into normal functions and I'm compiling with `-g3 -gdwarf-2`.

```
void gc_collect_root(void **ptrs, size_t len) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        void *ptr = ptrs[i];
        VERIFY_MARK_AND_PUSH(ptr);
        gc_drain_stack();
    }
}
```

The macro is:

```
// ptr should be of type void*
#define VERIFY_MARK_AND_PUSH(ptr) \
    do { \
        if (VERIFY_PTR(ptr)) { \
            size_t _block = BLOCK_FROM_PTR(ptr); \
            if (ATB_GET_KIND(_block) == AT_HEAD) { \
                /* an unmarked head, mark it, and push it on gc stack */ \
                DEBUG_printf("gc_mark(%p)\n", ptr); \
                ATB_HEAD_TO_MARK(_block); \
                if (MP_STATE_MEM(gc_sp) < &MP_STATE_MEM(gc_stack)[MICROPY_ALLOC_GC_STACK_SIZE]) { \
                    *MP_STATE_MEM(gc_sp)++ = _block; \
                } else { \
                    MP_STATE_MEM(gc_stack_overflow) = 1; \
                } \
            } \
        } \
    } while (0)
```

**QUESTION**

Is there any way to step into macros containing multiple lines of code?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to step into macros containing multiple lines of code?

You *can't* step into the macro regardless of whether it has single or multiple lines, because the preprocessor expands the body of the macro before the complier sees it.

A macro is simply a shorthand, a cut/paste if you will, so there is *nowhere* to step into -- it all becomes part of the current function.

To understand this better, look at preprocessed code (output from `gcc -E foo.c`).